# Trouble Creating a DFS Maze

Tags: java, depth-first-search

```
import java.util.*;

public class MazeGenerator
{
public void init()
{
    String Maze[][] = new String [20][20];

    for (int i =0; i <20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            Maze[i][j] = "#";
        }
    }

    generate(Maze);

    for (int i =0; i <20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + Maze[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public void generate (String Maze[][])
{
    Stack <String> CellStack = new Stack<String>();
    int TotalCells = Maze.length * Maze.length;
    int x = 10, y = 10;

    String CurrentCell = Maze[x][y];
    Maze[x][y] = "-";
    CellStack.push(CurrentCell);
    int VisitedCell = 1;

    boolean EastT, WestT, NorthT, SouthT;

    while(VisitedCell < TotalCells)
    {
        String EAST = Maze[x+1][y];
        String WEST = Maze[x-1][y];
        String NORTH = Maze[x][y+1];
        String SOUTH = Maze[x][y-1];

        if(EAST == "#")
            EastT = true;
        else
            EastT = false;

        if(WEST == "#")
            WestT = true;
        else
            WestT = false;

        if(NORTH == "#")
            NorthT = true;
        else
            NorthT = false;

        if(SOUTH == "#")
            SouthT = true;
        else
            SouthT = false;    

        if(WestT == true || EastT == true || NorthT == true || SouthT == true)
        {
            double Random = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;

            switch ((int) Random)
            {   
                case 1: 
                if(EastT == true){   
                    CurrentCell = EAST;
                    break;
                }
                else 
                    break;

                case 2:
                if(WestT == true){   
                    CurrentCell = WEST;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    break;

                case 3:
                if(NorthT == true){   
                    CurrentCell = NORTH;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    break;

                case 4:
                if(SouthT == true){   
                    CurrentCell = SOUTH;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            CurrentCell = "-";
            CellStack.push(CurrentCell);
            VisitedCell++;
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentCell = CellStack.pop();
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I print it out I get a Maze that has all "#"'s in it (with one "-" in the first location), meaning that the Maze was not created the correct way. But I cannot see why it doesn't work. I think that it may have to do with the CurrentCell variable, but I am unsure. Can anyone help me find out my error, I have been trying to find it but to no avail. Much appreciated!

Comment: Change `String Maze[][] = new String [20][20]` into `char Maze[][] = new char[20][20]`: then you can use `... == '#'` instead of `...equals("#")`

Comment: Watch the naming conventions... When naming variables, the first word is not capitalized and subsequent words are. Also, don't capitalize every letter of a variable name unless it is explicitly declared `final` (referring to your `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, and `WEST` variables).

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  This doesn't completely fix your program, but it fixes a problem in your code:

You do a lot of testing for `if(EAST == "#")` (or similar commands).  However, you cannot use `==` with strings, as this compares their reference.  You must use `.equals()`.  So, you'd use instead: `if(EAST.equals("#"))`.

I also don't see where you're changing the contents of the Maze[][] array.  It just seems like you're editing a stack, but ignoring the array you end up printing at the end.

Style tweaks:

1. If you have boolean variable (let's call it `var`), you don't have to use `if(var == true)`, instead, use `if(var)`.
2. Don't use if/else statements to assign boolean variables.  For example:

   ```
   if(WEST == "#")
       WestT = true;
   else
       WestT = false;
   ```

   Can be simplied to:
   `WestT = WEST.equals("#");`

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your implementation. You are right to see the biggest problem is with the CurrentCell variable. It is ONLY a String variable and you are changing the value of a variable but never touched the real values of the maze cells except the cell at (10,10).

Suggestion: create a Cell object to represent a cell of the maze with properties x, y coordinates, char  "#" or "-" as maze cell value, and a boolean "visited" to indicate whether or not it has been visited. Update x, y coordinates for the current cell. After each move set the current cell value.